# Site looks differently on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, text, fonts

My site looks different on mobile, it doesn't show coming soon and doesn't have the correct fonts. What's wrong?
Here you can see on mobile https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fdS7.jpg and here it is on my computer https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqncM.png

the website is rushir.co/lofty

Comment: You should put the codes you used in the question itself instead of linking to your website only. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: This is what I get http://i.imgur.com/hqgAu7x.png

Comment: And this on mobile http://i.imgur.com/Y3v92s3.png

Answer (score 0):

The font is displaying on your desktop because, I'm pretty sure, you have the font installed on your system.

Your line that loads the `ttf` file is incorrect:

```
src: url("font/Pacifico.ttf") format("truetype");
```

It needs to be relative to your css file:

```
src: url("../font/Pacifico.ttf") format("truetype");
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out so then if I have an issue i'll know what it it. What if the "font/Pacifico.ttf" is uploaded in the "font" directory?

Comment: It *is* in the font directory.  Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: By installing the font on his system.  Front-end developers and graphic designers often do this in order to use custom fonts in graphical tools like PhotoShop.  The installation steps for installing a font on ones system is system-dependent and not all operating systems support the same fonts format.

Comment: So fonts installed on a system can render into a website?

Comment: In my experience, yes.